# User authentication in google gadget

Tags: authentication, google-gadget

I'm creating a google gadget (for igoogle or gmail) which will make requests to my server.
I wanted to know if there was any way for me to authenticate users without having them authenticate with username/password on my server. is there a way to use the google identity to identify the users (does google give me the google userID in some way?).
If i were to use the Oauth option in google gadgets would i be able to get the access_token and use that as an identifier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following parameters, it will make google send you a signed request with the open social id :

```
params[gadgets.io.RequestParameters.CONTENT_TYPE] = gadgets.io.ContentType.JSON;
params[gadgets.io.RequestParameters.AUTHORIZATION] = gadgets.io.AuthorizationType.SIGNED;
params["OAUTH_SERVICE_NAME"] = "HMAC";
params[gadgets.io.RequestParameters.METHOD] = gadgets.io.MethodType.GET;
```